# java.io.NotSerializableException: java.lang.reflect.Constructor

Tags: java, swing, serialization, stream, jtable

I want to serialize an Model from my `JTable`, unfortunatly I got an `NotSerializableException`.
All of my fields are `Serializable`, I can't understand where is the problem here.

```
public class Sauvegarde extends AbstractAction implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public DefaultTableModel model;

    public Sauvegarde(String string) {
        super(string);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        sauve_actionPerformed(e);
        System.exit(0);

    }

    public void sauve_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        this.model = Grille.dfm;
        try {

            // Serialisation
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("sauve.tmp");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(model);
            oos.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the class where I create the JTable and the model :

```
    String[] columnTitles = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
    String[] cellulesVide = { "", "", "", "", ""};
    String[][] rowData = new String[nombreDeLignes][5];

    dfm = new DefaultTableModel(columnTitles,0);


    //table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);


    for (int i = 0 ; i < nombreDeLignes ; i++)
    {   
        dfm.addRow(cellulesVide);
    }


    table = new JTable(dfm) {
```

Comment: The answer is in the question: your model references an instance of java.lang.reflect.Constructor, and this class is not serializable.

Comment: Désolé je ne comprend pas, DefaultTableModel est une classe Serializable d'après la doc ...

Comment: The table model stores a vector of the item models. What type of items are you storing in the model? Are you sure those are properly serializable? Perhaps post some code of the class you're using for the item models?

Comment: I just store Strings in my model. I I was inspired by this link :
http://www.javafr.com/codesource.aspx?ID=24694

Comment: If you stored only strings, you wouldn't get an exception. Show us the code creating and populating the model, and the full stack trace of the exception. And always close your streams in a finally block.

Comment: Ok, I edited my previous post, you can see where I create my Table and affect my model.
But, you didnt think that the problem can appear because I added listener to my model ?
Thanks for helps !

Comment: @superstarz Maybe so but until you show us that code it is impossible to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

No magic.

You should check all classes and their fields in the hierarchy of your object.
All fields and classes should be Serializable or primitive.

Parent may not be serializable, but it must have a default constructor.

It the conditions above are true, it should work.

Comment: Of course, I did that, as you can see, this class contain just 1 field and this class is Serializable. 
In normal condition, Exception inform me which class is in conflict, but here the exception dont say nothing ..

Comment: @superstarz ok, then step by step. What is this Grille.dfm?

Comment: @superstarz Tried your example with fake Grille, having field public static DefaultTableModel dfm; which I initialized in a static block. Everything works. Your example is missing some detail. What is nombreDeLignes? int numberOfLines = 5, or something else? And are you sure, no code overwrites dfm?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you directly or indirectly have a non-transient data member of type Constructor, which is not Serializable, as the exception says. Find it and make it transient, or eliminate it. Constructors aren't Serializable.